# Подскажите как можно реализовать такую навигацию для слайдера

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике на определенный год происходит плавная прокрутка к этому году, также меняются картинка + текст выше навигации, подскажите как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Тебе необходимо каждый год сделать кнопкой. Присвоить этой кнопке, скажем какой-то класс, повесить на него обработчик события, и data атрибут в котором хранить значение поворота этого колеса. Дальше по нажатию на определенную кнопку считывать значения угла поворота который ты хранил в data атрибуте, и делать анимацию с нужным транзишеном анимации. (Значения data перезаписывать относительно текущего положения колеса ) Картинки менять с привязкой к этим кнопкам... Я бы так делал